# Bounded Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I came across the following problems during the course of my self-study of real analysis:

> Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n = 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{n}$ is unbounded.

I know a sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded if there exists a positive number $K$ such that $|x_n| \leq K$ for all $n$. So suppose for contradiction that it is bounded. Maybe we can define sequences $a_n = x_n-1$, $b_n = a_n-\frac{1}{2}$, $c_n = b_n- \frac{1}{3} \dots$ and try to come up with a contradiction?

> Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_1 = x$,  $x_{n+1} = x_{n}+ 1/x_n$ is unbounded.

Suppose for contradiction that $(x_n)$ is bounded by $K$ for all $n$. Then show that there is some $K' < K$ which is also an upper bound?

> Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n = 1+ \frac{1}{2!}+ \frac{1}{3!} + \dots + \frac{1}{n!}$ is bounded above by $2$.

So there is some relationship between $n!$ and $2^{n-1}$. I think $n! \geq 2^{n-1}$ and we can prove this by induction on $n$? So $x_n \leq 1+1+ \frac{1}{8} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$?

Comment: It's relatively easy to prove that $n! \geq 2^{n-1}$ using induction, so I'd go with that.

Comment: Problem 1: the traditional trick for this is to notice $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \cdots + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots + \frac{1}{16} + \cdots > 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \cdots + \frac{1}{16} + \cdots.$ This has to be made rigorous, of course.

Comment: For part 2) [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/given-a-1-1-a-n1-a-n-frac1a-n-find-lim-n-to-infty-fraca) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29777/find-a-closed-form-for-this-sequence)

Comment: For part 1) [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30907/how-to-solve-this-limit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The simplest way to show that a sequence is unbounded is to show that for any $K\gt 0$ you can find $n$ (which may depend on $K$) such that $x_n\geq K$.

   The simplest proof I know for this particular sequence is due to <strike>one of the Bernoulli brothers</strike> Oresme. I'll get you started with the relevant observations and you can try to take it from there:

   Notice that $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ are both greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{4}$, so
   $$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\geq \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

   Likewise, each of $\frac{1}{5}$, $\frac{1}{6}$, $\frac{1}{7}$, and $\frac{1}{8}$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{8}$, so
   $$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} \geq \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
   Now look at the fractions $\frac{1}{n}$ with $n=9,\ldots,16$; compare them to $\frac{1}{16}$; then compare the fractions $\frac{1}{n}$ with $n=17,\ldots,32$ to $\frac{1}{32}$. And so on.

   See what this tells you about $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_4$, $x_8$, $x_{16}$, $x_{32}$, etc.
2. Your proposal does not work as stated. For example, the sequence $x_n = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ is bounded by $K=10$; but it's also bounded by $K=5$. Just because you can find a better bound to *some* proposed upper bound doesn't tell you the proposal is contradictory. It *might*, if you specify that you want to take $K$ to be the *least upper bound* of the sequence. Even so, it's hard to establish that a sequence is unbounded that way. (Note also that you haven't really defined the sequence very well: it is undefined for $x=0$, though that is the only problem.)

   To get you started: Show that if you start the sequence with $-x$ instead of $x$, then you just get the same sequence multiplied by $-1$. That is, if you fix $x\neq 0$, and you let $y_1=-x$, $y_{n+1}= y_n + (1/y_n)$, then $y_k = -x_k$; so the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded if and only if the sequence $y_k$ is bounded, and so you may assume $x\gt 0$.

   Then show that if $0\lt x\lt 1$, and you let $y_1 = \frac{1}{x}$, $y_{n+1} = y_n+(1/y_n)$, then $y_k=x_k$ for $k\geq 2$; so you may assume that $x\geq 1$.

   Now you have that the sequence is increasing. If it were bounded, it would converge, say to $L\gt 0$. Then
   $$L = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x_n + \frac{1}{x_n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n + \frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n} = L+\frac{1}{L}.$$
   I think that's a very big problem for $L$...
3. Yes, if you can prove that $n!\gt 2^{n-1}$ for all $n\geq 1$, then you can bound your sequence by a sequence of powers of $\frac{1}{2}$; if you can show *that* sequence is bounded, you'll be done. And, yes, you can prove the inequality in question by induction on $n$. It's very simple to do. But you messed up your computations later (that second $1$ should be a $\frac{1}{2}$). If $n!\geq 2^{n-1}$, then
   $$\begin{align*}
   x_n &= 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!} \\
   &\leq 1 + \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\\
    &= \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2^n}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}}\\
    &= \frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}\\
   & = 2 - \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.\end{align*}$$
   Almost done!

Comment: @Arturo: For (1), $x_1+ x_2+ x_4+ x_8 + x_{16} + \dots > 1/2$.

Comment: @Damien: That's not nearly good enough to show the sequence is unbounded. I mean, you already knew it was greater than $1$ (since $x_1=1$), so saying it's also greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't say anything you didn't already know. Remember, you want to show that for *any* number $K$, you can *eventually* get more than $K$.

Comment: @Arturo: All of those terms are $> 1/2$. So given some $K$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n >N$, $a_n \geq K$. Take $N = 2K$.

Comment: @Damien: What you said was that the sum of *all* is greater than 1/2; that's true, but not useful. If you mean to say that *each* of the terms $x_{2^n}$ is greater than $1/2$, that's also true, but again *not helpful*. It's not helpful because you aren't trying to show that the *sum* of the $x_i$ is unbounded, you are trying to show that the $x_i$ **themselves** are unbounded. You are trying to show that for any $K$, you can find $N$ such that $x_N\gt K$; if all you know is that $x_{2^N}\gt 1/2$, that doesn't help you for $K=10$.

Comment: @Arturo: $x_{2n}-x_{n} \geq 1/2$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Damien: Better, but still not quite what you want. Shoulnd't you be looking at $x_{2^n}-x_{2^{n-1}}$?

Comment: @Arturo: So $x_{2^n}-x_{2^{n-1}} > 1/2$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin:  The now "standard" argument for the divergence of the harmonic series was given by Oresme, more than $300$ years before one of the Bernoullis gave a proof of the divergence. The Bernoulli argument is a curiously convoluted manipulation.

Comment: @user6312: Ah, thanks. I'll fix the attribution.

Comment: @Damien: Yes. And from there you can get that $x_{2^n}\gt n/2$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The first part was answered in Grotaur's answer. The third part you did it yourself.

For the sequence $x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}$, first note that if the first term is positive so are all the others; if the first term is negative, so are all the others. Suppose that the first term is positive, and therefore the sequence is increasing ($x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{1}{x_n}>0$.)

Suppose now that the sequence is bounded. A bounded increasing sequence is convergent, and denote by $L$ it's limit. Take $n \to \infty $ in the recurrence relation, and see what values could $L$ have.

Comment: For the third part I proved that it is less than $2+a$ but not less than $2$ where $a = \frac{1}{8} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: You made a too large majorisation. You have $1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{6!}+...\leq 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...=2$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider terms $s_k = x_{2^k-1} - x_{2^{k-1}}$. Prove that $s_k\geq \frac{1}{2}$ and note that $x_{2^n}\geq s_1+s_2+...s_n\geq \frac n 2$.